# How to pass JWT token on client side?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I have 2 pages. One page is for registration and the second is for User detail. On the registration page, the user will enter his details and register. My problem is after registration I want to redirect the user to the detail page where only registered users can see their information.

I am using JWT for authentication. After registration when I receive token I do not know how to pass it on to the next page. I want to set a header for the token. but after receiving token when I set header then this header lost when I redirect on next page. I am not sending any ajax request and also I am using simple html and hbs for template engine.

Comment: Is this true?  You call your api for registration, and api sends back to client token. If so, you can save the token in browser's localStorage and use the token to call user info api in detail page.

Answer (score 1):

- Once you get token from server side keep that in **cookies** or **local storage** in browser with time out.
- Next create common method for read token from **local storage** or **coockies** then amend that token into request headers using **Interceptor** for all ajax calls

Note: Go through about Interceptors

Comment: But I am not making any ajax request. So How can I access this token on client side so that i can use it for local storage ? . Problem is I have my token on server side. and I am redirecting to another URL and then I lost my token.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not working on `REST APIs`, you can use the session for the authentication of the user.

So that everything will be handled in the backend. `Passport` is a good package for handling the user authentication.

Comment: Yes I am not working on REST APIs and I want to develop a web application in node js. But how can I use sessions in node js ? .

Comment: you may need to use express session and passport to implement this, 
check https://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/